Prove that the operator is not compact
Problem:

Prove that the operator $A\in\mathcal{L}\left ( C[0,1] \right ):(Af)(x)=f\left ( x^2 \right )$ is not compact

My attempt at a solution:
It is necessary that the image of the unit ball be precompact. Here, in the space of continuous functions, precompactness is governed by Arzel's theorem. About limitation and equal continuity. Considered the image of all functions for which $\sup |f(x)| \leq 1$ by $x \in [0, 1]$
How can we approach the problem differently and prove compactness?

What is $\mathcal{L}\left ( C[0,1] \right )$?

Your operator is what is called a composition operator; if $s:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is the map $s(t)=t^2$, then $A(f)=f\circ s$. Note that
$$\|A(f)\|_{C[0,1]}=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|A(f)(t)|=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t^2)|=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|=\|f\|_{C[0,1]}$$
This shows that $A$ is an isometry, and therefore cannot be compact: take any sequence of continuous functions $(f_n)$ with $\|f_n\|=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and such that, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f_n(1/k)=0$ for all $k=1,\dots,n-1$ and $f_n(1/n)=1$ (you can define these piecewise linearly).
Since $(f_n)$ is bounded, if $A$ was compact we would have that $A(f_n)$ has a convergent subsequence. However, $A(f_n)$ does not have any Cauchy subsequence, since for $n\ne m$ (say $n>m$) we have $$\|A(f_n)-A(f_m)\|=\|A(f_n-f_m)\|=\|f_n-f_m\|\ge|f_n(1/m)-f_m(1/m)|=|0-1|=1.$$

related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737787/equivalent-conditions-for-composition-to-be-compact-operator

Thank you! A very beautiful solution!

Assuming you mean $C[0,1]$ with the supremum norm, take the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=x^n$. Clearly this is a bounded sequence. However, the sequence $Af_n(x)=x^{2n}$ has no convergent subsequence. (any subsequence converges pointwise to a non continuous function, and so can't converge uniformly on $[0,1]$)

The operator is invertible with $(A^{-1}f)(x)=f(\sqrt{x}),$ thus $A^{-1}\circ A=I.$ Clearly $I$ is not compact, so $A$ cannot be compact.
